# Inequality related to the decimal representation of a positive integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, natural-numbers

Let $S(m)$ be the sum of digits in decimal notation of a positive integer $m$, and $f(n)$ be the number of ways to represent $n$ in the form $n=a+b+c$, where $a,b,c$ are different positive integers such that $S(a)=S(b)=S(c)$.

Find all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(n)>n$.

I have a hypothetical answer: $153$, as well as all numbers that are multiples of three, starting with $159$. There are many ways, and there are more and more of them. It is necessary to get an estimate for some number, and everything less is checked by computer search.

Comment: Is this a project euler problem or similar?

Comment: @dbx I don't know. More likely no than yes.

Comment: To rule out $0$ , you can replace "natural numbers" by "positive integers". This issue cannot occur anyway as soon as $n>0$ since if one of $a,b,c$ were $0$, all were $0$.

Comment: @Peter Yup. Or else "non-negative integer".

Comment: Did you do this computer search to approve that the smallest solutions are $153$ and $159$ ?

Comment: Does the order of the numbers in the triple matter ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, using the program. But I did it a long time ago, so most likely it was extremely primitive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132012/discussion-between-peter-and-cornifer).